# autofac Register closed subclasses of abstract open generic

Tags: autofac

```
public class Sub1 : Base<SomeClass>
{
   // for sake of getting injection to work, not injecting anything in ctor
   public Sub1() {}
   ....
}

public class Sub2 : Base<SomeOtherClass>
{
   // for sake of getting injection to work, not injecting anything in ctor
   public Sub2() {}
   ....
}

public abstract class Base<T> 
{
   // abstract, so no ctor
   ....
}
```

I tried the following but I'm getting the exception listed below. Notice it the exception references the Base abstract class. What am I missing?

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Base<>).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base<>))).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(Base<>)).InstancePerDependency();
```

**No constructors on type 'Base`1[SomeClass]' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.**

Comment: Can you show your constructor implemantations.

Comment: Edited to show simple constructors. I assume I'm missing something in the registration but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mixed with generic and non generic abstract class registrations.

You have generic abstract class. Therefore your register should be like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Base<>).Assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(Base<>)).InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: Still getting the exception. Tried adding an IRepository<> interface to the abstract and do builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IBase<>).Assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof (IBase<>)); but that didn't work either even though I've seen blogs that state it does.

Comment: Can you share how you resolve also. I didn't get error.

Comment: I see the problem, the closed type of the specific generic type I tried to resolve was located in another assembly that wasn't registered. Meaning I registered the types in the assembly of IBase but the type within <> was in another assembly that I didn't register. Thanks for your help.